Using Group By in Update Query
I am trying to calculate weight using update.
In the specific case I need to apply grouping as the burden needs to be distributed by cliend id.
But the grouping is not working correctly here.
It is mandatory to use update
Results

Expected result:
the expected result is to have allocated
by weight based on client id and holdings
0.14/0.14/1/0.71
    CREATE TABLE VALUE_TBL 
     ( CLIEND_ID NUMBER(10),
       VALUE NUMBER,
       WEIGHT NUMBER,
       HOLDINGS VARCHAR(50)
     );

insert into value_tbl1(cliend_id,value,WEIGHT,HOLDINGS) values(1,10,33.33,'GOOGLE');
insert into value_tbl1(cliend_id,value,WEIGHT,HOLDINGS) values(1,10,33.33,'AAPL');
insert into value_tbl1(cliend_id,value,WEIGHT,HOLDINGS) values(2,30,100,'ABB');
insert into value_tbl1(cliend_id,value,WEIGHT,HOLDINGS) values(1,50,33.33,'TESLA');

I tried the following update but no success
  update value_tbl y
  set weight = value / 
  (select sum(value) 
  from value_tbl x 
  group by x.cliend_id)


'no success' doesn't tell us much; it's helpful to include the result or error you get; you showed data (as an image - please don't do that, use formatted text) suggesting you're currently updating to null, but your query will error as it is. Your query also uses sum, which wouldn't give the result you showed either, and your description isn't entirely clear. (And your inserts have typos...) Please edit your question to clarify what you want and what is wrong.

Error report -
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

OK, so what result do you want - 33.33/33.33/1/33.33 as you've shown, or something like 0.14/0.14/1/0.71? Please edit the question to explain your logic and expected result.

Your subquery will return one row for every ID, not just the total for the ID you are updating. As a correlated update that would look like:
update value_tbl y
  set weight = y.value / 
  (select sum(x.value) 
  from value_tbl x 
  where x.cliend_id = y.cliend_id)




CLIEND_ID
VALUE
WEIGHT
HOLDINGS




1
10
.1428571428571428571428571428571428571429
GOOGLE


1
10
.1428571428571428571428571428571428571429
AAPL


2
30
1
ABB


1
50
.7142857142857142857142857142857142857143
TESLA



Which is not the result you showed. To get those percentages you would use the count, and divide into 100, not value:
update value_tbl y
  set weight = 100 / 
  (select count(*) 
  from value_tbl x 
  where x.cliend_id = y.cliend_id)




CLIEND_ID
VALUE
WEIGHT
HOLDINGS




1
10
33.33333333333333333333333333333333333333
GOOGLE


1
10
33.33333333333333333333333333333333333333
AAPL


2
30
100
ABB


1
50
33.33333333333333333333333333333333333333
TESLA



fiddle
You can use the round, floor/ceil or trunc functions to limit the results to two decimal places, or change your column definition to only store two decimal places.
